# BlackBerry - Develope Cropit Like Application

Tags: image, graphics, blackberry, blackberry-storm, crop

i want to develop cropit like application, i just want to know how to increase or decrease the size of the rectangle over the image (multitouch events), which define the image portion to be cropped.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onTouchEvent, look for DOWN and MOVE events to correctly draw selection.

To make simulator multitouch: Alt+T and then use left mouse button for finger 1 and right mouse button for finger 2.

Code sample:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {

    XYPoint mLeftUp = null;
    XYPoint mRightBottom = null;
    XYPoint mCoursor = null;
    // Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("wallpaper_bold.jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("wallpaper_storm.jpg");
    BitmapField mBitmapField = new BitmapField(bitmap);

    public Scr() {
        add(mBitmapField);
        mCoursor = new XYPoint(bitmap.getWidth() >> 1,
                bitmap.getHeight() >> 1);
    }

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
        if (mLeftUp != null && mRightBottom != null) {
            menu.add(new MenuItem("crop", 0, 0) {
                public void run() {
                    XYRect rect = null;
                    if (mLeftUp.x > mRightBottom.x
                            && mLeftUp.y > mRightBottom.y) {
                        rect = new XYRect(mRightBottom, mLeftUp);
                    } else {
                        rect = new XYRect(mLeftUp, mRightBottom);
                    }
                    Bitmap crop = cropImage(bitmap, rect.x, rect.y,
                            rect.width, rect.height);
                    mBitmapField.setBitmap(crop);
                    mCoursor = new XYPoint(crop.getWidth() >> 1, crop
                            .getHeight() >> 1);
                    mLeftUp = null;
                    mRightBottom = null;
                    invalidate();
                }
            });

            menu.add(new MenuItem("reset", 0, 0) {
                public void run() {
                    mBitmapField.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    mCoursor = new XYPoint(bitmap.getWidth() >> 1, bitmap
                            .getHeight() >> 1);
                    invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        if (mCoursor != null) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.drawLine(mCoursor.x - 4, mCoursor.y - 4,
                    mCoursor.x + 4, mCoursor.y + 4);
            graphics.drawLine(mCoursor.x + 4, mCoursor.y - 4,
                    mCoursor.x - 4, mCoursor.y + 4);
        }
        if (mLeftUp != null && mRightBottom != null) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.drawPoint(mLeftUp.x, mLeftUp.y);
            graphics.drawPoint(mRightBottom.x, mRightBottom.y);
            graphics.drawPoint(mLeftUp.x, mRightBottom.y);
            graphics.drawPoint(mRightBottom.x, mLeftUp.y);
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
            XYRect redRect = null;
            if (mLeftUp.x > mRightBottom.x && mLeftUp.y > mRightBottom.y) {
                redRect = new XYRect(mRightBottom, mLeftUp);
            } else {
                redRect = new XYRect(mLeftUp, mRightBottom);
            }
            graphics.drawRect(redRect.x, redRect.y, redRect.width,
                    redRect.height);
        }
    }

    // comment block for Bold
    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        int x1 = message.getX(1);
        int y1 = message.getY(1);
        int x2 = message.getX(2);
        int y2 = message.getY(2);
        switch (message.getEvent()) {
        case TouchEvent.DOWN:
            if (x1 != -1) {
                mLeftUp = new XYPoint(x1, y1);
            } else if (x2 != -1) {
                mRightBottom = new XYPoint(x2, y2);
            }
            break;
        case TouchEvent.MOVE:
            if (x1 != -1) {
                mLeftUp = new XYPoint(x1, y1);
            }
            if (x2 != -1) {
                mRightBottom = new XYPoint(x2, y2);
            }
            break;
        case TouchEvent.UNCLICK:
            mLeftUp = null;
            mRightBottom = null;
        default:
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status,
            int time) {
        moveCoursor(dx, dy);
        return true;
    }

    private void moveCoursor(int dx, int dy) {
        mCoursor.translate(dx, dy);
        if (mLeftUp != null) {
            mRightBottom = new XYPoint(mCoursor);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    protected boolean navigationUnclick(int status, int time) {
        clickCoursor();
        return true;
    }

    private void clickCoursor() {
        if (mLeftUp != null && mLeftUp.equals(mCoursor)) {
            mLeftUp = null;
            mRightBottom = null;
        } else {
            mLeftUp = new XYPoint(mCoursor);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public static Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap image, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.create(result);
        g.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, image, x, y);
        return result;
    }
}
```